# Find a role for each GCP services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm making an app where a user can choose a set of GCP services, and then, the full access to those services are granted by the app. I'm trying to figure out how for each services I can associate a role, in an automatic way, that grant the access to this specific service.

Example :

```
User choice | Role granted

Big Query  ----> roles/BigQueryAdmin
Firestore  ----> roles/FirestoreAdmin
Pub/Sub    ----> roles/PubSubAdmin
```

I'm searching how can I create those admin roles, any ideas ?

Comment: You will need to create your own table and update that table often as Google-managed IAM roles are updated and new ones are created by Google. For your problem, you must clearly specify how users are authenticating and how you are granting permissions. Google is locking down the granting of permissions for OAuth. In some cases your app with then require a security audit. Details matter to get an answer that is correct.